# IIS AppCmd syntax for setting credentials for virtualDirectory

Tags: iis, appcmd

I'm using `appcmd` to create a new virtual directory in IIS8. The syntax for this is:

```
appcmd add vdir /app.name:<NAME> /path:<PATH> /physicalPath:<PHYSICAL-PATH>
```

This works fine. Now I need to set some credentials; this is easy in the GUI (virtual dir > basic settings > connect as). When I set this, I can see in my `applicationHost.config` file that it is updating an XML entry. So I should be able to set that manually with `appcmd`. I'm struggling with the syntax to navigate to the right XML element so I can set the attribute `userName` and add the attribute `password`.

Here is my XML:

```xml
<sites>
  <site name="EXAMPLESITE" id="4">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="EXAMPLEPOOL">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\wwwroot\" userName="" />
        <virtualDirectory path="/upload" physicalPath="\\SOME-COMPUTER-ON-NETWORK\upload" userName="" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
</sites>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
appcmd set vdir /vdir.name:"EXAMPLESITE/upload" /userName:user /password:password
```

Comment: Work fine! Thanks @Kev I just managed to get it to work with the following syntax as well. But your solution is much cleaner. 

_appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites "/[name='EXAMPLESITE'].[path='/'].[path='/upload'].userName:<USERNAME>" "/[name='EXAMPLESITE'].[path='/'].[path='/upload'].password:<PASSWORD>" /commit:apphost_

Comment: @Olle excellent. Yeah, there are quite a few ways to do the same thing with appcmd. Glad I could help.

Comment: It also works for IIS Express, but `/apphostconfig` might be required there.